# Is "I'm confused how it works" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Is "I'm confused how it works" grammatically correct?

Or should it be something like "I'm confused about how it works?"

I hear and see Americans say the first, but as a native Mandarin speaker it is more difficult for me to parse.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm confused how...* is informal.

[Google's Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=confused%20about%20how%2Cconfused%20how&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconfused%20about%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconfused%20how%3B%2Cc0) says *confused about how* is more popular in publishings of late.

[image: Ngram]

Answer (score 1):

I say: "I am confused (as to) how/ why..." and I feel that this is more appropriate and formal. There are many other ways to say it, but I'd say that this way is the best.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm confused about how it works" is more clear and direct.

"I'm confused how it works" elides either "by" or "about" and is therefore less clear, even though it may be grammatical and acceptable usage for some English speakers.